# Time complexity of exponentiating s-sparse matrices

Tags: time-complexity

Could someone suggest me a reference which discusses the time complexity of algorithms meant for exponentiating (finding $e^A$ approximately given $A$) [s-sparse matrices](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4004/26), along with their error rates?

P.S: I'm mostly interested in Hermitian matrices $A$.

Comment: this is probably relevant here: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0508139